# Data Pipeline using SQl and Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, data-pipeline

I need to create a data pipeline using Python. I want to connect with MySql in Python and read the tables in dataframes, perform pre-processing and then load the data back to Mysql Db. I was able to connect to the MySql Db using mysql connector and then pre-process the dataframes. However, I'm not able to load these dataframes from Python back to Mysql. Error: ValueError: unknown type str96 python.
Please help me with methods to complete this task.

I'm new to programming. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and has been fixed in version 1.1.3.

upgrade `pandas` package

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```